# while if statement php

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to put in an if statement after SQL query?

I have this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM oppgave WHERE modulid AND myusername ='{$_SESSION['myusername']}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling); 

while ($nesteRad = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>Du har levert Modul: " . $nextrow['modulid'];
        echo "<br>";
```

-modulid is  a column that hold value from 1-6.

I'm trying to insert this after while:

```
if ($modulid['modulid'] < 5 ) {
    echo "less than 5";
}

if ($modulid['modulid'] > 5) {
    echo "More than 5";
}
```

But it not working as I was hoping. Any tip?

Comment: Your code seems open to SQL injection. Also; [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your `$modulid` - array doesn't exist.

in your `while(){}` - loop you are iterating through the result-array where each row is saved in `$nesteRad` according to your example. so i think your code isn't working at all, cause you are using the variable `$nextrow` for your output.

in your example it's not possible to output something depending from the field 'modulid' after
the while-loop in a correct way. cause you are iterating through the result array within the while loop and after it `$nesteRad['modulid']` would just give you the value of the last 'modulid'-column found in your query.

and the value of your 'modulid'-column could be different in every row of your mysql-result-set.

so you would have to echo it inside your while-loop like this for example:

```
while ($nesteRad = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($nesteRad['modulid'] < 5)
    {
        echo "less than 5";
    }
    else if($nesteRad['modulid'] > 5)
    {
        echo "more than 5";
    }
}
```